# Find the Missed call count in Android

Tags: android, call, calllog

Is there a way to find the missed call count in Android. I used call Log and I am able to get the total number of missed calls in the call log but not the missed calls after the last time the user visited the call log.

For eg the user has 1 missed call then it will be displayed in notification bar but when user visits the call log then this count is cleared and from next time the notification is not displayed until there is a new missed call. I would like to simulate the same behavior.

Thanks,
Prabhu

Answer (score 0):

you should store the previous missed call count in `sharedPreference` ...

you can invoke native call log screen and from here you can get the notification that the call log has been visited:

```
Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
context.startActivity(showCallLog);
```

Comment: But how will I know if the user has viewed the call log so that I can clear the missed call count...

Comment: you want to implement this in your app then you need to implement custom log screen for your app....or when you invoke the native call log screen thru your app as I have added in the above answer ..